# react set environment file for webpack config .env, .env.test and .env.production

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

below is the package.json configuration for my react application

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development",
"prod": "webpack --mode=production"
}
```

How do I set .env, .env.test and .env.production environment variable to pass the values to `process.env`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).
I recommend using cross-env for app which are not run in docker container

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env MODE=development webpack-dev-server --mode=development",
}
```

So you will have access to process.env.MODE in your webpack config file

If you want to get access to proccess.env in your client code you should use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

Comment: Can you please suggest how do I use environment files like .env and .env.production. I am not going to pass the variable in command line